# Markov chain with absorbing probability $a/b$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I need to build Markov chain with probability of absorbing $a/b$ (rational number) and probabilities of transitions $1/n$ for all states for given numbers $a/b, n$. ($n$ is positive integer)

My attempt was to represent $a/b$ in base $n$ and consider uniformly distributed random variable $X$ that outputs values $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ with probability $1/n$ and keep playing with it until it outputs value different from $i$-th digit of $a/b$ in base $n$.

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track...

Comment: Yes that's good! Generate a random real number between 0 and 1 by generating its "digits" in base n. If the kth digit of the random number is strictly lower than the kth digit of a/b, then go to the absorbing state. If the kth digit of the random number is strictly higher than the kth digit of a/b, go to a rejecting state. If the kth digits are equal, keep generating more digits. At first glance it looks like you need an infinite number of states (to keep track of k) but actually, rational numbers are guaranteed to have a repeating expansion in any base, so you needonly a finite numberofstates

Comment: (For instance if n=10 and a/b=1/3 then you will always compare the generated digits to 3 because 1/3 = 0.333333..., so you don't need to keep track of k at all; and if n=10 and a/b=123/999 = 0.123123123... then you only need three states to keep track of whether the next digit needs to be compared to 1,2 or 3

Comment: @Stef thank you so much for help !